# Как вставлять переменные в текст?

Tags: java

В `python`, например, есть удобная функция `format`:

```
'This is {which} text '.format(which='incredible')
```

Какие подобные удобные штуки есть в `java` ?

Answer (score 5):

Есть аналогичный метод `String.format`

Пример: `String.format("This is %s text", "incredible");`

Более подробно можно ознакомится [в доках к java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)